# How to save excel file from http response to server side using C# 1.1 framework

Tags: c#, .net-1.1

Currently my steps is opening a new page with all the details inside the `aspx` and in the code behind is coded below.

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=TenatReport.xls");
```

So the page will be converted to excel file and system will prompt to save the excel file to their local folder. This is currently working fine and no problem at all.

Now I need help and advise on how to save the excel file to the server instead of saving in local folder without the prompting message. Is there a way using the `http` response output stream to save the page to the server side or perhaps output stream to save in the database as binary then I will retrieve from the database as binary.

Please note I am still using 1.1 framework.

I tried this code below but it logs out the url after calling the wc.

```
string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), _TenantID.ToString() + ".xls");

System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();<br>
wc.DownloadFile("url:web/Alltenantsrep.aspx?dtmonth=1&dtyear=2014", fileName);
```

Kindly help as I am stuck for a week. thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you generating the Excel file?

Comment: my aspx page has a placeholder for the ascx control inside, the ascx have all the datagrid that is bound from the database, once it is called I just put the 
response.addheader and system will prompt to download it as excel file. The excel file can be download by the users. 
However I need the excel file to be dynamic save to server temporarily instead of asking customer to download the file.

Comment: And why is that not working with the `WebClient`?

Comment: When I call the URL it is losing the session, it gets back to the login page.

Comment: any advice ? 

after i call the url aspx with the parameter and download the file, the file I am downloading is the login page, this is due to the cookies

Comment: I would generate the output directly to a file, but seems that you're generating HTML to be picked up by Excel. You'll need to pass the cookies you received from the browser. One of them is the authentication cookie. Unfortunately another one is the session state cookie and, unless you're using in-proc session state, one of the requests is going to timeout.

Comment: I manage to solve the issue in the authentication by creating new site. However I still having problem when generating the output as excel, instead of excel it save as HTML. 
it seems the code does not work in the codebehind. 

Response.ClearContent();<br>
Response.ClearHeaders();<br>
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";<br>
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sExcelFileName + ".xls"); <br>
<br>
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();<br>
wc.DownloadFile(rls, fileName);<br>

Comment: The fact that Excel is able to open HTML files doesn't mean they are really Excel files, no matter the extension you give to the file.